# why the position of searched item in list item becomes "ZERO"

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using a listview and search bar. When I click on any searched item to send in another activity, it sends 0. WHEN I SEARCHED AND CLICKED, this is my problem
what should I do the get the real position when I searched (to get the default position)?

```
   wordSearch = findViewById(R.id.search_text);
   listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
   items = wordsArray ;
   arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
    @Override`enter code here`
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
    position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(search.this, lektion1.class);
            String sendData = wordsArray[position] ;
            intent.putExtra("sendData",sendData);
            long selectedId = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            intent.putExtra("id",String.valueOf(selectedId));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

           }
        });

         adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> 
        (this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.tv,arrayList);
         listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    wordSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int 
    count) {
        search.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```